# Construct a tensor of tf.Variable objects

Tags: python, tensorflow

My cost function involves the matrix

```
T=[[1.0-a,b],[a,1.0-b]]
```

I can define

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a=0.3
b=0.4
T = tf.Variable([[1.0-a,b],[a,1.0-b]]
```

and this works well in the optimization, but then I am saying that I have four variables: 1-a,b,a,1-b (the gradient has four elements). On the other hand, I would like my variables to be two: a and b (the gradient has two elements).

I thought of doing something like

```
var = tf.Variable([a,b])
T = tf.constant([[1.0-var[0],var[1]],[var[0],1.0-var[1]]])
```

but this does not work, outputing the following:

```
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

So how can I construct a tensor made of tf.Variable objects?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of cost function is this `T=[[1.0-a,b],[a,1.0-b]]`? In what sense is this a cost function?

Comment: I said my cost function involves T. To be specific, my cost function will depend on vector elements of r = T^N v, where v is just [1,1], and N is some large number. Actually, as you might infer, r is just the dominant eigenvector of T, when N is large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(0.3)
b = tf.Variable(0.4)
T = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1.0 - a, b], [a, 1.0 - b]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise T as a placeholder.

```
T = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 2])
```

When starting your session, compute T and pass it in through a `feed_dict`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, b = .3, .4
    inp = np.array([[1 - a, b], [a, 1 - b]])
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={T : inp})
```

Where `optimizer` is the node that minimizes your cost function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @jdehesa answer was more helpful because I need to use tf.Variable since I am using pymanopt (https://pymanopt.github.io/), see section c in Cost Functions.